# Azure AD authentication access without admin consent to application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I created a app service/website in Azure portal keeping in view that the access should be restricted inside my organization.
I created a app using azure app registration, and used the tenant, client id to implement azure active directory authentication.
I do not have permission for activating admin consent for the registered app due to policy restrictions. I added 2 owners for the registered app.
Now how can I enable access to everyone inside my organization. Is admin consent really required to enable access to users inside organization?
What would be other options other than enabling admin consent?

Comment: if you only want to allow all users in your tenant to sign in your application with their tenant account, then you only need to create the aad app and generate a client secret and use them into your app, that's enough. no need to get admin consent. admin consent is for consenting api permissions which used to call graph api.

Comment: have you met any issue yet? like someone can't sign in your app?

Comment: When I open website in browser, it shows "Admin consent required warning/error" and stops accessing site.

Comment: pls go tp azure ad-> app registration->the app you created -> api permissions -> checking how many api permissions are added there and if they required admin consent. Per my understanding, when a new app created, there should only one `user.read`...

Comment: There is only one user.read

Comment: sorry then I don't have any ideas on that, I'm afraid that the admin had set some policy in your tenant which stops you. Maybe you need to contact the admin to confirm it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to authenticate Wep App using Azure AD**

I have created App Service like below.

**Azure Portal > App Services > Create**

One create the App Service test the application and copy the App **URL**

[image]

Create App Registration in Azure Active Directory.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > New Registration**

[image]

After the Application registration enable ID Token ,like below

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Your Web Application >  Authentication**

[image]

If you want to customize your application, modify your application like below.

[image]

Add the Scope to your application like below.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Your Web Application > Expose an API > Set next to Application ID URI and Add Scope**

**Add Scope** : *user_impersonation*

[image]

Enable Azure AD identity provider to your App Service application like below.

**Azure Portal >App Service > Select your App Service > Authentication >  Add Identity provider**
[image]

```
Endpoint Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant-ID/v2.0
```

Finally logged in to my web application with Azure AD Credentials.

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#advanced

Comment: Where are we using the created client secret here?

Comment: Hi Kurkula, Client secret is optional, it's not mandatory to create a secret key in your application. refer doc for more details.

Comment: What are we doing in this step "User Assigned role in Azure AD"? Should this process be done for each and every user who needs access to the application?

Comment: yes, I just added for your reference only, by default all users are able to access the application.

Comment: will it work without adding Identity provider?

Comment: Yes,but application will open without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to resolve the "admin consent" dialog when logging in

[image]